# parsing app_access_token like described in facebook documentation

Tags: php, facebook, parsing, facebook-graph-api

I have to retrieve the app access token of my facebook application to use FQL statements.

I've read in the documentation that you have to make a GET request so i wrote this lines of code after including the php fb sdk:

```
$app_access_token = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?


client_id=".FB_APP_ID.",


&client_secret=".FB_APP_SECRET.",


&grant_type=client_credentials;";
```

After this step the documentation says that you have to parse the string to obtain the value of the app access token, but i can't understand how?

I've tried the parse_url php function in this way

```
parse_url($app_access_token);
echo $app_access_token;
```

But the result was only to print the $app_access_token url.

Which way i have to follow?

Thanks

Comment: You can simply copy&paste access tokens for your apps from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse the query string, you should use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) instead:

```
parse_str($app_access_token, $params);
echo $params['app_access_token'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct way to do that, but anyway it doesn't display me anything..

Comment: @FabioRossi: Can you post the output of `echo '<pre>' . print_r(app_access_token, true) . '</pre>'` to http://pastebin.com and link here?

Comment: @FabioRossi: Uh, what? You just copied that code into pastebin? Add that in your script, copy the output, paste it into pastebin.com, link here.